# ASP.NET Web Forms password authenication on a single page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I´m building a site using ASP.NET with C#, built from the Web Forms template.

One of the pages needs to be protected with a password, much like the PHP authenticate.

I´ve tried several samples but then all the pages in the application is protected, I just need the authentication when a specific page is requested.

Any good and simple ways to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two immediate options that come to mind:

1. Specifically exclude pages that you do not want under the `Forms Authentication` security using the `location` element in the `web.config` file, like this:
2. Put all of the pages that you do not want security applied to in a folder and apply a separate `web.config` to that folder. The steps to perform this are detailed in [Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx)

Comment: "like this: " - what's missing?